# $f$ not measurable, but $\lvert f\rvert$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Do you know an example of a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is **not** $\mathcal{B}$-measurable but $\lvert f\rvert$ **is** $\mathcal{B}$-measurable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pick any non-measurable set $A$. Define:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &: x \in A \\
-1 &: x \not\in A
\end{cases}
$$

$|f| = 1$ is a constant function, hence measurable. $f$ is easily seen to be non-measurable.

Comment: What a great example and so easy!... Thank you!

Comment: @math12 You're welcome. :)

Comment: $f$ is non-measurable because for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$   the preimage is one of $A, A^C, \Omega,\emptyset$ and $A\notin\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $A^C\notin\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Right? To be honest, I do not know a set that is not in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$^^

Comment: @math12 Your first statement is correct. As for the second, $\mathbb R$ has $2^\mathfrak c$ subsets, but there are only $\mathfrak c$ Borel sets. Here is a [proof](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m103f08/public_html/borel-sets-soln.pdf) of this fact (it's usually proved early on in measure theory books). If you want an explicit example of a non-Borel set, check out this [article](http://planetmath.org/ALebesgueMeasurableButNonBorelSet).